# How a free sucession of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error, malloc, free

So I have struct that has two pointer tags inside it: next, which points to a chain of other structs (all linked by pointers their next field as well) and the other one points to the last struct in the chain. I'm trying to free them but somehow I keep getting a core dump due to an invalid free. I'm a new C coder. Is there something I am doing that's obviously wrong?

```
void free_if(myTik *the){


    while(the->endif != NULL){
        myTik *eh;
        eh = the->next;
        the->next = the->next->next;
        free(eh);
    
    }
   
}
```

Comment: If `the->next` is NULL, then `the->next = the->next->next;` is problematic.

Comment: Too little code posted. How is `myTik` defined? How is the linked list constructed? Also it's unclear what this function should do... it's called `free_**if**` which suggests a conditional free but there is no if-statement.

Comment: Not using a debugger.  Not following/detailing your test/debug strategy and results, (does it work on an empty list?  Does it work on a list of one?  Two?  Three?

Comment: As a new user, you should read [ask]. Specifically, your code is not a [mcve] so others cannot reproduce. And reproducing the problem is often a required step to find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is an error in your logic.

You check if 'current node' is NULL or not, but erase 'next' of current node.

```
the->next = the->next->next;
```

so above code can be error if

node(current) -> NULL (because the->next is NULL, so the->next->next will corrupt run-time error)

it is better to use 'dummy header' to erase total node in one-way linked-list

```
void free_if(node header){

  while(header->head->next != NULL){
    node *eh;
    eh = header->head;
    header->head = eh->next;
    free(eh);
  }

  //if escape while loop, you get this
  //HEADER(dummy) -> node -> NULL;

  so, just free it
  free(header->head);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to work down you linked-list, node-by-node, saving a copy of the current pointer (the victim to delete) and advancing the pointer you are using to iterate over your list before freeing the memory of the victim node. (you were close, you just had too many `->next` thrown in there)

A normal traversal freeing all nodes is:

```
void free_if (myTik *the)
{
    while (the != NULL) {
        myTik *victim = the;
        
        the = the->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```